# How to deploy blockchain app in heroku

Tags: web3js, blockchain, dapp-development, nodejs, ganache

I want to deploy my blockchain app in heroku and i just want to use ganache as my blockchain network. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in the subject but I think your app can be deployed to heroku and use Ganache as the blockchain network as long as the user has ganache installed on their local machine. I will try myself and update here if I am successful.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using Ganache in Heroku you can save all Addresses and Private keys from Ganache in a list and use it when needed.